# Should I use redirect 301 for htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

Here is the code I'm using to always add https and www to my code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I've read about making the redirect = 301 and was wondering if and how I should do that?

Comment: maybe this will help to understand it better https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

Comment: @jakob So if I want the website to ALWAYS have https and www then I should make it `[R=301,L]`?

Comment: well it is called `301 Moved Permanently` so if it is permanent redirect then yes

Comment: @jakob feel free to make it an answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

301 redirect is used for permanent URL redirection so, in your case, `[R=301,L]` should be used.

[Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633) states this:

> If you need to change the URL of a page as it is shown in search engine results, we recommend that you use a server-side 301 redirect. This is the best way to ensure that users and search engines are directed to the correct page. The 301 status code means that a page has permanently moved to a new location.

And also according to [Google HTTPS directions](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6073543) 301 redirect is considered a best practice for HTTPS redirects.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to have 301 redirection, much better than 401 (google doesn't like it).